# Integrate TURN|STUN with XMPP

Tags: domain-name-system, xmpp, ejabberd

How do XMPP clients find TURN or STUN servers? [XEP-0215](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0215.html) isn't supported (by any servers or clients afaik), but [XEP-0176](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0176.html#deploy) suggests using XEP-0215?

I am running both an XMPP and TURN server, and I would like XMPP client to be informed or discover my TURN server. What do pidgin/empathy (the clients I need to support) do? Is there a canonical cross-client approach? Possibly:

- Embed information in disco (XEP-0030 - would be misuse)
- Servers use XEP-0114 to work some "magic"
- Clients check DNS records
- Clients check host (derived from JID) @ well-known port
- Clients do nothing (I hope not)

Thanks.

Also I am asking in the context of Jingle/ICE/RTP, however this applies to any use of TURN with XMPP.

Answer (score 2):

Some XMPP clients (e.g. libpurple-based clients such as Adium and Pidgin) use DNS SRV records, cf.:

http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records#STUN_SRV_records

```
_stun._tcp.example.net. TTL IN SRV priority weight port target
_stun._udp.example.net. TTL IN SRV priority weight port target
```

e.g.

```
_stun._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 3478 server1.example.net.
_stun._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 30 3478 server2.example.net.
_stun._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 3478 server3.example.net.
_stun._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 3478 server4.example.net.
_stun._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 15 0 3478 backup.example.net.
_stun._udp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 3478 server1.example.net.
_stuns._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 5349 server1.example.net.
```

http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records#TURN_SRV_records

```
_turn._tcp.example.net. TTL IN SRV priority weight port target
_turn._udp.example.net. TTL IN SRV priority weight port target
_turns._tcp.example.net. TTL IN SRV priority weight port target
```

e.g.

```
_turn._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 3478 server1.example.net.
_turn._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 30 3478 server2.example.net.
_turn._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 3478 server3.example.net.
_turn._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 10 10 3478 server4.example.net.
_turn._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 15 0 3478 backup.example.net.
_turn._udp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 3478 server1.example.net.
_turns._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 50 5349 server1.example.net.
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Please refrain from using link-only answers; they're only useful so long as they remain valid. Referring to them in your answer is fine, but some actual content is necessary.